# http ping to restart service

Tags: windows, http, ping

This tool checks if a website is offline or not.
http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/http-ping/

I'm trying to create an automated process to run that file and check domain.com, if pinging fails then stop --> start apache.

They have a sample code on their website witch i have slitly modified and looks like,

```
@echo off
REM This batch file is for use with AlwaysUp (http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) or Service Protector (http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceProtector/)
REM Copyright � 2001-2012 Core Technologies Consulting, LLC. All rights reserved.


REM Ping your web server
REM *** Please change the location of http-ping.exe if necessary and adjust the URL to point to your web server ***
"C:\http-ping.exe" http://www.domain.com

REM http-ping returns the percentage of pings that succeed. With 4 attempts, this can be 0, 25, 50, 75, or 100.
REM Any of the 4 pings succeeds consider it a success ==> return 0 so that AlwaysUp doesn't restart
IF ERRORLEVEL 25 GOTO success
IF ERRORLEVEL 50 GOTO success
IF ERRORLEVEL 75 GOTO success
IF ERRORLEVEL 100 GOTO success

REM Exit code of 0 ==> all failed ==> return 1 to have AlwaysUp restart the application
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO failure


REM http-ping returned a code < 0 ==> there was some other kind of failure. Don't restart, but have AlwaysUp log the failure ==> return 2
echo http-ping failed!
net stop Apache2.4
net start Apache2.4
exit 2

:success
echo Succeeded!
exit 0

:failure
echo Failed!
net stop Apache2.4
net start Apache2.4
exit 1
```

But it doesn't work.
Using Windows, Apache, and i'm using the schedule feature in OS to automate it.

The regular windows ping utility can't do what i'm looking for.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What does it do?  "it doesn't work" isn't very descriptive.  Can you run the http-ping.exe manually?  Are you specifying full path in the task scheduler?

Comment: The command runs successfully and returns correct response, but doesn't stop & start apache.

Comment: Did you verify that the name of the apache service is indeed Apache2.4?  Do a net start and see what apache is called then update your script.